# CKEditor UI Space not being defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

`editor.ui.space` is being set to `null` when I try to run the `ckeditor` function.

Im pulling in my content with ajax, on success or done, I then insert the html into the dom, then straight after that I try to bind my editors with default options.

Example:

```
$.get('url', function(data){
    $('body').html(data.content);
    $('textarea.content').ckeditor();
});
```

This dies straight away because ui-spaces aren't being set. I have no idea why, but if I set a timeout, of say 500, and the run the ckeditor function, it works fine.

```
$.get('url', function(data){
    $('body').html(data.content);
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        // This does work fine with no problems, why?
        $('textarea.content').ckeditor();
        clearTimeout(t);
    }, 500);
});
```

Why does this not work after it's inserted into the dom...

Comment: Try using `console.log(editor.ui);` with your browser's developer tools, take a look at the console tab and take a look at the `ui` object property to see if it has a `space` property, or something similar to help you look into your issue.

Comment: space is a function is it not ? @Pricey but no it doesn't have any space properties, neither do my other ones on other pages and they work fine.

Comment: sorry yea, a lot of things in javascript are objects, including functions so thats why I used the word object. The error that you are getting shows the result from calling the space function is returning null. The `space` function you are calling seems to be part of the `ui` object http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui, not any space plugin. This is what the function does: http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/ui.html#CKEDITOR-ui-method-space so this to me looks like it's just searching for your editor's ui by the name and can't find it.

Comment: Okay, narrows it down a bit, what can I do do fix it? I have no idea why it's not working :( @Pricey

Comment: Would be useful to see the rest of the code really, my thought would be it is to do with the order of the code that is initialising your editor space... but it might be something else, i.e. inside a frameset that isn't accessible or something else.

Comment: I am ajaxing in my content, then after I set the html, I run the ckeditor function, if I set a timeout of say 500, then run the ckeditor function it works? @Pricey

Comment: The space function is definitely trying to find an element with an id of `contents`, all I can suggest at the moment without seeing more code, html and references etc, is just to make sure that when your doing the `editor.ui.space('contents')` call it is inside a dom ready wrapping function http://api.jquery.com/ready/ and that there is definitely a `contents` element available after the document is ready.

Comment: From your latest comment, the problem is that you need to use your space function in a callback function.. i.e. in .done http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: It `isn't` trying to find an element with the id of `contents`. It's trying to find an instance object. I'm calling the ckeditor function on success of an ajax call. @Pricey

Comment: the space function calls a getById function that does the below: `var $ = this.$.getElementById( elementId ); return $ ? new CKEDITOR.dom.element( $ ) : null;` that to me looks like it's trying to find an element by it's id and then makes a CKEDITOR special dom element out of it... your problem is due to the space function being called before this is available from your ajax result, so just make sure you do that work in a callback.

Comment: Yes, but its an instance created BY ckeditor, the shared spacing function creates these sections automatically, it's not created by me, so this isn't the problem unfortunately @Pricey

Comment: Yes but what I'm saying is that your calling `editor.ui.space('contents')` before CKEditor has had a chance to create all this stuff for you.

Comment: Example, the `spaceId` function returns something like : `cke_1_contents`

Comment: I'm not calling the space function, that's just where it's dieing in the ckeditor source code. I have edited my answer with our new found results @Pricey

Comment: Ah ok sorry my misunderstanding, but the problem is still the same one, CKEditor can't find the content space because it hasn't been created yet, which is why you see it working when setting a timeout, please update your question with example code so that a solution can be provided.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today.

In my case I just change:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"defer></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, I have noticed that if I omit or disable app.js script from the head section, this problem disapears.

Look at the head section and find out

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Now delete it or Comment it.

```
//<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Note that:
app.js script is required if you use vue.js in your page. If so, you have to find out alternative solution.

I do not use vue.js, so I delete it without worry.

**Note:**

I know, it is not a mature answer. But It can help other to find out a real solution.

Comment: in laravel app.js must be include before ckeditor.js

Answer (score 0):

The jquery `html` function is synchronous but the content still takes time to load and this is sometimes not yet available when calling `$('textarea.content').ckeditor();`

Please try this instead of the timeout, to make sure the contents is available before initialising the ckeditor, timeout is a solution but it is not a reliable one.

```
$.get('url', function(data){
    $('body').html(data.content).promise().done(function() {
         $('textarea.content').ckeditor();
    });

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either :( Isn't promise only related to fx?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins .promise can be used in the above example, but I guess it depends on what version of jQuery you are using. I am not sure what is happening in your case, maybe your issue is being caused by some other bit of code that isn't shown above, as having to use a timeout still suggests to me that something isn't available at the appropriate time that ckeditor is initialised.

Comment: It's definitely weird, before I run anything, I'm checking the length of the textarea, so it should be in the dom so ckeditor shouldn't have a problem binding to it right? Definitely weird :(

Comment: @ShannonHochkins yea there is definitely more to it than just the markup that it is being bound to. Is there any other dependencies that are being loaded async?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            //CKEDITOR
            CKEDITOR.replace('selector_ID');
            CKEDITOR.config.height = 100;
            //END CKEDITOR
        },0);
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a web site using AngularJS and JQuery. It seems to be solved just by initalizing CkEditor (version 4...) in the JQuery *'document.ready()'* directive, to ensure that it is the last Javascript library to be run.

```
<script language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
    }
 );
 </script>
```